# Java Generics-- Incompatible types Required:java.io.filedescriptor Found:java.lang.object

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I use JNI to call c function in order to create interface.
I am getting below error message on android studio

Incompatible types
Required: java.io.FileDescriptor
Found: java.lang.Object

packet.java

```
FileDescriptor myDev= null;
myDev = JNI.prepare_fd("/dev/net/tun", myDev); =>this line hava above error
in2 = new FileInputStream(myDev);
```

JNI.java

```
    public class JNI {
           static {
                     System.loadLibrary("JNITest");
           }
           public static native Object prepare_fd(String filename, FileDescriptor fdobj);
   }
```

packet_JNI.h

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_packetcapture_JNI_prepare_fd (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring );
```

JNITest.c

```
    JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
    Java_com_example_packetcapture_JNI_prepare_1fd(JNIEnv *env, jclass _ignore, jstring filename)
    { 
    jfieldID field_fd;
    jmethodID const_fdesc;
    jclass class_fdesc, class_ioex;
    jobject ret;
    int fd;
    char *fname;

    class_ioex = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/IOException");
    if (class_ioex == NULL) return NULL;
    class_fdesc = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/FileDescriptor");
    if (class_fdesc == NULL) return NULL;

    fname = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);

    fd = open(fname, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, filename, fname);

    if (fd < 0) {
        // open returned an error. Throw an IOException with the error string
        char buf[1024];
        sprintf(buf, "open: %s", strerror(errno));
        (*env)->ThrowNew(env, class_ioex, buf);
        return NULL;
    }

    // construct a new FileDescriptor
    const_fdesc = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class_fdesc, "<init>", "()V");
    if (const_fdesc == NULL) return NULL;
    ret = (*env)->NewObject(env, class_fdesc, const_fdesc);

    // poke the "fd" field with the file descriptor
    field_fd = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, class_fdesc, "fd", "I");
    if (field_fd == NULL) return NULL;
    (*env)->SetIntField(env, ret, field_fd, fd);

    // and return it
    return ret;
    }
```

Can anyone give me some idea? How to fix this error. Thank you.

Comment: your JNI method signature is mismatching.

Comment: where's jni code block is signature mismatching ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following line says that it's a generic object type:

```
public static native Object prepare_fd(String filename, FileDescriptor fdobj);
```

Easiest fix is to cast it to a filedescriptor when setting myDev:

```
myDev = (filedescriptor) JNI.prepare_fd("/dev/net/tun", myDev);
```

Comment: When I add  filedescriptor, it can compiler, thank you